# Strip out HTML and Special Characters

Tags: php

I'd like to use any php function or whatever so that i can remove any HTML code and special characters and gives me only alpha-numeric output

```
$des = "Hello world)<b> (*&^%$#@! it's me: and; love you.<p>";
```

I want the output become `Hello world it s me and love you` (just Aa-Zz-0-9-WhiteSpace)

I've tried `strip_tags` but it removes only HTML codes

```
$clear = strip_tags($des); 
echo $clear;
```

So is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Probably better here for a regex replace

```
// Strip HTML Tags
$clear = strip_tags($des);
// Clean up things like &amp;
$clear = html_entity_decode($clear);
// Strip out any url-encoded stuff
$clear = urldecode($clear);
// Replace non-AlNum characters with space
$clear = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', ' ', $clear);
// Replace Multiple spaces with single space
$clear = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $clear);
// Trim the string of leading/trailing space
$clear = trim($clear);
```

Or, in one go

```
$clear = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($des))))));
```

Comment: thanks a lot , it is very helpful and works perfect also thanks for explaining it step by step.

Comment: *chuckles* I'd +1'd yours as soon as I saw it :D

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function html_entities_decode()

Comment: doesn't that code replace *alphanumerics* with spaces, rather than **non**-alphanumerics? that is: shan't the `/[A-Za-z0-9]/` be inverted?

Comment: I took the example and wrote a function (modifying it to allow for simple punctuation). function superSanitize($entry){ $j = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 .,@!?()-]/", ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($entry)))))); return($j); }

Comment: Any thoughts on escaping `'` and `"` in the regex?

Comment: All those solutions strip also diacritics like ç or à.

Comment: Very helpful! I finally filled out all those html tags and link spams for my client's review page

Comment: Work exactly what i needed

Answer (score 13):

Strip out tags, leave only alphanumeric characters and space:

```
$clear = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strip_tags($des));
```

**Edit:** all credit to DaveRandom for the perfect solution...

```
$clear = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($des)));
```

Comment: +1 for Matt, but you should probably make `strip_tags($des)` into `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($des))` or you are at risk of ending up with some stray `amp`, `lt`, `gt` etc in the output...

Answer (score 6):

All the other solutions are creepy because they are from someone that arrogantly simply thinks that English is the only language in the world :)

All those solutions strip also diacritics like ç or à.

The perfect solution, as stated in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), is simply:

```
$clear = strip_tags($des);
```

Comment: Yea, as a english speaker can understand what you are saying. Your solution is perfect for my issue. Was trying to use too many rules and diacritics were getting stripped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a more detailed manner from Above example, Considering below is your string:

```
$string = '<div>This..</div> <a>is<a/> <strong>hello</strong> <i>world</i> ! هذا هو مرحبا العالم! !@#$%^&&**(*)<>?:";p[]"/.,\|`~1@#$%^&^&*(()908978867564564534423412313`1`` "Arabic Text نص عربي test 123 و,.m,............ ~~~ ٍ،]ٍْ}~ِ]ٍ}"; ';
```

Code:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&*().]/u','', strip_tags($string));
```

`Allows:` English letters (Capital and small), 0 to 9 and characters `!@#$%^&*().`

`Removes:` All html tags, and special characters other than above

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I liked this idea so much.

Comment: @JackBen: glad to see your response :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one single line :)
specially useful for GET or POST requests

```
$clear = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', urldecode($_GET['id']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I've been using that I've put together from various threads around the net that removes everything, all tags and leaves you with a perfect phrase.  Does anyone know how to modify this script to allow periods (.) ?  In other words, leave everything 'as is' but leave the periods alone or other punctuation like and ! or a comma? let me know.

```
function stripAlpha( $item )

{

    $search     = array( 
         '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si'   // Strip out javascript 
        ,'@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU'    // Strip style tags properly 
        ,'@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si'            // Strip out HTML tags
        ,'@<![\s\S]*?–[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA
        ,'/\s{2,}/'
        ,'/(\s){2,}/'

    );

    $pattern    = array(

         '#[^a-zA-Z ]#'                     // Non alpha characters
        ,'/\s+/'                            // More than one whitespace

    );

    $replace    = array(
         ''
        ,' '

    );

    $item = preg_replace( $search, '', html_entity_decode( $item ) );
    $item = trim( preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, strip_tags( $item ) ) );
    return $item;

}
```

Comment: How to have UTF-8 characters acceptable,but remove other special caharacters

Answer (score 0):

to allow **periods** and any other **character** just add them like so:

change: '`#[^a-zA-Z ]#`'
to:'`#[^a-zA-Z .()!]#`'

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '',$string)` this is using for removing special character only rather than space between the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all special character don't give space write in single line

```
trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', 
urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($string))))));
```