# What kind of these characters and how I trim it with PHP

Tags: php, html

This maybe a dumb question. I have a site running which allows its users to submit their content.

Some of users are playing with strange characters (to me) which I don't want to see. Here are some of these:

```
▄ █ ▄ █ ▄ █ ▄ █ ▄
```

What kind of and how can I trim these characters? I have tried some method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128856/strip-out-html-and-special-characters) but how can I do it without having to loose the html special characters like © ® ... etc.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to have a look at Regular expressions for input validation http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Would you allow Chinese characters, though? Can you restrict it to English only?

Comment: Characters shouldn't break the styling? How does that work?

Comment: Yes Jack I can restrict Chinese. Is that chinese? No Nanne, I meant the overall look. sorry for that.

Comment: In which way they break the styling? You need to formulate the real problem first, to avoid disallowing things on wrong grounds. The FULL BLOCK characters in the example are higher than normal characters, as they occupy the entire height of the font. But good layout design accommodates that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could strip out characters based on their Unicode properties like this:

```
// strip out symbols
echo preg_replace('/[\p{S}]+/u', '', 'Hello ▄ █ ▄ █ ▄ █ ▄ █ ▄ World');
// Hello World
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q6E1eR)

You can read more about Unicode capabilities of regular expressions in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

Unfortunately, the above code also strips out your copyright and trademark symbols; you may want to consider making exceptions for those characters, e.g.:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{Z}©®]+/u', '', 'Hello ▄ █ ▄ █ ▄ █ ▄ █ ▄ World © ®');
```

Comment: @rzkio Be aware that it also strips the symbols you may want to have.

Comment: Am I have to include all the special characters to the function?

Comment: @rzkio Yeah, the problem is that Unicode has ranges for particular characters, it just so happens that the characters you want and don't want fall into the same category :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars().

htmlentities()

This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

htmlspecialchars:

Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with some of these conversions made; the translations made are those most useful for everyday web programming. If you require all HTML character entities to be translated, use htmlentities() instead.

The difference is encoding. The choices are everything (entities) or "special" characters, like ampersand, double and single quotes, less than, and greater than (specialchars).

Comment: htmlentities() would print html special chars as a plain text which I don't want to. But thanks though!