# PHP Regex find word that begins and ends with a charecter

Tags: php, regex

I need to strip a certain character if it is at the starts and end of a word.

eg: `"I am a ?small? string"`

Should be  `""I am a small string""`

Thank you

Comment: Check this: http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: What if the string is like "I am? a small string"  only at the end or start of word

Comment: What have you tried? And is it just the question mark, or any arbitrary character?

Comment: Please refer this: [Strip out Special Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128856/strip-out-html-and-special-characters) @Niall

Comment: You can use `echo preg_replace('/[?]/','',$string);`. You can add your characters within braces as per your requirement [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/41)

Comment: @NarendraSisodia That will remove the character anywhere, not just at the beginning and end of words.

Comment: Why does the result have extra double quotes at the beginning and end?

Comment: Yes you're right @Barmar

Comment: Use lookarounds to match space before and after the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

With this regex:

```
/[?](\b\w+\b)[?]/
```

You can select the word cointained by all you put in the brakets.

With:

```
preg_filter('/[?](\b\w+\b)[?]/', '${1}', "I am a ?small? string")
```

The output will be:

> I am a small string

[Here the Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ8jH3/1)

Comment: This also removes the `?` in `I am a very?small? string` even though they're not at the beginning of the word.

Comment: That's because `\b` will always match between `?` and a letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))\?(\w+)\?(?=\s|$)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/14