# Show HTML special characters as is

Tags: php, html, highcharts, special-characters, html-entities

I need to display a few item names as it is stored in database. It is working fine except when the name contains HTML special characters. For eg: if the name is like `&lt;ItemName&gt;` it is showed as `<ItemName>` when echo it using PHP. How can I prevent this. Also if the name is stored in DB as `<ItemName>` it should show like that only. When I tried to use `htmlentities()`, it is showing the `&` as `&amp;` and that isn't what I need to show. How this can be fixed ?

Also I am using Highcharts and it has the item names as labels. So the name `<ItemName>` (if with tags), needs to be converted to `htmlentities()` in order to display it correctly. Otherwise, it will not show the label.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128856/strip-out-html-and-special-characters - strip special characters?

Comment: *"When I tried to use htmlentities(), it is showing the & as &amp;"* – please be a lot clearer about what you're doing and what result you get. `htmlentities` is exactly the solution you need, it's unclear what's not working for you. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function

```
<?php
echo(htmlspecialchars('<ItemName>something</ItemName>'));
```

or as in your case:

```
<?php
echo(htmlspecialchars('&lt;ItemName&gt;something&lt;/ItemName&gt;'));
```